# Capturing the position of node filtered from an IF condition in XSLT v1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

The following is my input. Upon transformation, I want the first value filtered through a condition to be printed in the "first" element and the remaining to be printed in "rest" element.

**Input XML:**

```
<root>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>5</a>
    <a>6</a>
    <a>7</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>9</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>11</a>
    <a>12</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>0</a>
    <a>15</a>
    <a>16</a>
</root>
```

In the following XSLT, say, it is mandatory to have the for-each and the if condition within. As position captures at the level of for-each, the first input filtered through the if condition is not at position 1, resulting in undesired output.

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/a">
                **<xsl:if test=". != 0">**
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                            <first-value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </first-value>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <rest>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </rest>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output from the above XSLT**

```
<root>
    **<rest>5</rest>**
    <rest>6</rest>
    <rest>7</rest>
    <rest>9</rest>
    <rest>11</rest>
    <rest>12</rest>
    <rest>15</rest>
    <rest>16</rest>
</root>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
    **<first>5</first>**
    <rest>6</rest>
    <rest>7</rest>
    <rest>9</rest>
    <rest>11</rest>
    <rest>12</rest>
    <rest>15</rest>
    <rest>16</rest>
</root>
```

How to print the first filtered value in an element and the remaining in a separate element? Is there an alternate approach as to what I have taken?

Comment: Well, why do you say "it is mandatory to have the for-each and the if condition within"? Why can't you use a  predicate `for-each select="root/a[. != 0]"`?

Comment: @Martin:The input I have shown here is a sample and it captures a glimpse that only represents my difficulty. In the actual case, the for-each and the if condition can't be combined, the if block is only a part of the for-each block. That's why I have mentioned them as mandatory.

Comment: Neither the posted input nor the wanted output give us any indication as to what additional processing you need to do. If you want to see alternative approaches I think it is better if you provide some context.

Comment: You've tagged the question xslt 1.0 and xslt 2.0 but you specify xslt 1.0 in your question title. Most problems (including this one) are easier to solve in XSLT 2.0, so you need to be quite clear what version you are able to use to avoid answerers wasting their time.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I am currently using XSLT 1.0 and haven't upgraded to XSLT 2.0 yet. I would be glad to know the approach in both the versions.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can use `xsl:for-each select="root/a[f:condition(.)]">` and within the `xsl:for-each` the value of `position()` will only consider the selected nodes. Unlike 1.0, there is no limit on the complexity of the condition in the predicate, because you can put the logic in a separate function declared using `xsl:function`.

Comment: @MichaelKay:Thank You,but is there any possibility or any methods in XSLT 1.0 to do the same.

Comment: Sorry, it's 15 years since I used XSLT 1.0 in anger and I really don't remember all the messy workarounds for things that ought to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="a[.!=0]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        <first><xsl:value-of select="."/></first>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <rest><xsl:value-of select="."/></rest>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/a">
            **<xsl:if test=". != 0">**
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(max(preceding-sibling::a) > 0)">
                        <first-value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </first-value>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <rest>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </rest>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a variable storing `<xsl:number count="a[. != 0]"/>` and comparing that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/a">
                <xsl:if test=". != 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="a-unequal-zero-index">
                      <xsl:number count="a[. != 0]"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$a-unequal-zero-index =1 ">
                            <first-value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </first-value>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <rest>
                                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                            </rest>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Whether that is all is an XSLT idiomatic way I am not sure, you haven't provided any context explaining the use of `for-each` and then the nesting of the `if` and `choose`.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiK8/1 has an online sample.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <root>
                <xsl:for-each select="root/a[. != 0]">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="position()= 1">
                                <first><xsl:value-of select="." /></first>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <rest>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </rest>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </root>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```